# Sending two variables with AJAX (I have one working but need two)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using the following code to send to a php script which adds to mysql database. The php code is working fine and set up to receive two variables but I am unsure how to change the ajax code to pass over 2 (or more) variables rather than 1 to the php script.
I have named the variable that is passed 'taskA' and want to add a 'taskB'

```
function add_task() {
    $('.add-new-task').submit(function(){
    var new_taskA = $('.add-new-task select[name=new-taskA]').val();

    if(new_taskA != ''){
    $.post('add-task.php', { taskA: new_taskA }, function( data ) {
    $('.add-new-taskA select[name=new-taskA]').val('');

    $(data).appendTo('.task-list ul').hide().fadeIn();

                delete_task();
            });
    }
    return false;

    });
}

function delete_task() {
    $('.delete-button').click(function(){
    var current_element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.post('delete-task.php', { task_id: id }, function() {
    current_element.parent().fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
    });
    });
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `{ taskA: new_taskA, taskB: new_taskB }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ taskA : new_taskA }` is one variable (one object). But an object can have many key/value pairs : `{ taskA: new_taskA , taskB : new_taskB}` is still **one** object you pass, but contains more stuff. You can pass as much data as you want this way : strings, numbers, objects, whatever.

Server-side, get this data back using :

```
$taskA = $_POST['taskA'];
$taskB = $_POST['taskB'];
```

Or even a generic loop to convert all your POST variables to PHP variables :

```
foreach ($_POST as $var => $value)  $$var = $value;
```

This will automatically set the `$taskA`, `$taskB`, `$taskWhatever` variables with corresponding values. Mind security though, and don't forget to sanitize the content.

Comment: Many thanks for all your responses. All answers were roughly the same so had to choose one to tick. It is working now! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass mulple value via `,` symbol
   { taskA: new_taskA ,taskB:new_taskB}

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$.post('add-task.php', { taskA: new_taskA, taskB: new_taskB }, function(...
```

Just add ',' between the variables.
Can be found from the bottom of the jQuery API-page:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

i.e:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```